# Stack two images side by side using Wand

Tags: python, image-processing, wand

How do I stack two images side by side, in wand (python)? Composite method is available, but it puts one image on top of another.
I want something like numpy.vstack .

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `smush()` with an optional spacing between images, and:

- `stacked=True` for vertical (one above the other) stacking, or
- `stacked=False` for side-by-side stacking.

---

```
from wand.image import Image

im = Image(filename="rose:")
with im as output:
    output.sequence.append(im)
    output.sequence.append(im)
    output.smush(True, 5)
    output.save(filename='result.png')
```

[image]

If you don't want any spacing between images, either make the `offset=0` or just use `concat()` rather than `smush()` but in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The `wand.image.Image.composite` method accepts `top` & `left` parameters. Not much effort to composite image side by side...

```py
with Image(filename="rose:") as left:
  with Image(filename="rose:") as right:
    with Image(width=left.width+right.width,
               height=max(left.height, right.height)) as output:
      output.composite(image=left, left=0, top=0)
      output.composite(image=right, left=left.width, top=0)
      output.save(filename="hstack.png")
```

[image: hstack]

... or stacked ...

```py
with Image(filename="rose:") as top:
  with Image(filename="rose:") as bottom:
    with Image(width=max(top.width, bottom.width),
               height=top.height + bottom.height) as output:
      output.composite(image=top, left=0, top=0)
      output.composite(image=bottom, left=0, top=top.height)
      output.save(filename="vstack.png")
```

[image: vstack]

Of course you may be able to simplify the examples above, or use `wand.api.library` to implement [`MagickAppendImage`](https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickAppendImages).

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.